# Angular + RxJS: use of takeUntil vs simple unsubscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm facing the following bit of code inside a component.

```
private _destroy$ = new Subject<null>();

// ...

ngOnInit() {
    this.someStream$
        .pipe(filter(a=> a !== null), takeUntil(this._destroy$))
        .subscribe(a => { });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this._destroy$.next();
    this._destroy$.complete();
}
```

Googling this matter gave me [one contrasted opinion](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87) regarding declarative code vs imperative, the latter being favoured by reactive architecture.

With that in mind, my question is: Compared to the way I've always approached the same case (illustrated with a snippet bellow), is there any other aspect than declarative vs imperative code? Also, how to confirm that the first approach ends up unsubscribing from the stream when `takeUntil's` predicate is complete?

```
private _subscription: Subscription = null;

// ...

ngOnInit() {
    this._subscription = this.someStream$
        .pipe(filter(a=> a !== null) )
        .subscribe(a => { });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this._subscription && this._subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Appart from

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490265/rxjs-takeuntil-angular-components-ngondestroy and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333939/angular-what-is-the-preferred-way-to-terminate-observables and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563065/difference-between-unsubscribe-to-take1

Comment: I think, suppose you've multiple subscriptions and you need to control all of them manually, then using `takeUntil` approach is good way to deal with it. For 2nd question about how to confirm how `takeUntil` work, you can read the source code, or create simple interval stream, then combine with `takeUntil` after amount of time.

Comment: @TiepPhan: it's not a question of basic idea of how `takeUntil` works. it's about detail: does it really unsubscribe, or does it just stop forwarding items? that's a bit harder to test than just creating a simple stream

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the takeUntil will send a "complete" signal to the subscribing party, allowing it to complete. This causes an unsubscribe.